# C++ Iterator: no appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, iterator

I am trying to implement Linked List with custom iterator.
I am getting a bunch of errors trying to implement copy constructor:

'LinkedListIterator>' : no appropriate default constructor available
'LinkedListIterator> LinkedList::begin(void)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer rom 'const LinkedList' to 'LinkedList &' 
'LinkedListIterator> LinkedList::end(void)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const LinkedList' to 'LinkedList &'

**LinkedList**

```
class LinkedList
{
std::unique_ptr<node> head;
std::unique_ptr<node> tail;

LinkedList(const LinkedList& other)
{
    init();
    iterator i = other.begin();
    while (i != other.end())
        add(*i++);

    head = other.head;
    tail = other.tail;
}

iterator begin() 
{
    return iterator(head->next);
}

iterator end()
{
    return iterator(tail);
}
```

**Iterator**

```
template <typename TNode>
class LinkedListIterator
{
    friend class LinkedList<typename TNode::value_type>;
    TNode* p;
public:
    LinkedListIterator(TNode* p) : p(p) {}
    LinkedListIterator(const LinkedListIterator& other) : p(other.p) {}
    LinkedListIterator& operator=(LinkedListIterator other) { std::swap(p, other.p); return *this; }
    void operator++() { p = p->next; }
    void operator++(int) { p = p->next; }
    bool operator==(const LinkedListIterator& other) { return p == other.p; }
    bool operator!=(const LinkedListIterator& other) { return p != other.p; }
    int& operator*() { return p->data; }
    LinkedListIterator<TNode> operator+(int i)
    {
        LinkedListIterator<TNode> iter = *this;
        while (i-- > 0 && iter.p)
        {
            ++iter;
        }
        return iter;
    }
};
}
```

Let me know if you need me to post more code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Member functions `begin()` and `end()`are defined as non-constant member functions

```
iterator begin() 
{
    return iterator(head->next);
}

iterator end()
{
    return iterator(tail);
}
```

However you call them for const object `other`

```
LinkedList(const LinkedList& other)
{
    init();
    iterator i = other.begin(); // <== here
    while (i != other.end()) // <== here
        add(*i++);

    head = other.head;
    tail = other.tail;
}
```

As for error mesdsage

> no appropriate default constructor available

then I do not see where the default constructor is used. Nevertheless the error message is clear enough: class `LinkedListIterator<Node<T>>` has no the default constructor but some where in the code you create an object of this type using the default constructor.

Comment: that was the problem, other errors went away as soon as I defined **const_iterator**. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 'iterator' is defined as 'LinkedListIterator' it appears that you are attempting to pass the 'head' and 'tail' variables (which appear to be global?) to constructors that do not exist and the compiler is making a last ditched effort to match against a copy constructor (for which there is no match).

I would assume that code should be as follows:

```
iterator begin() 
{
    return iterator(head->next.get());
}

iterator end()
{
    return iterator(tail.get());
}
```

Comment: I am sorry I didn't write code correctly they are part of LinkedList class (updated thread)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does the 'std::unique_ptr' your using have a builtin 'operator node*' operation to convert to 'node*'?

Comment: well it has a .get() function which returns the pointer to node